# HtmlFromHtml overrides text color selector on View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have a textview with a custom color selector setup in xml style.

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/light" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/dark" />
</selector>
```

I set the text like this:

```
mView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Some incoming html text"));
```

This overrides the current text selector on the view.

I've also tried to reset the selector like this:

```
mView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.sel);
```

I need to keep the style the same, any ideas?

Comment: may be this help setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.sel));

Comment: Tried this too.

Comment: Can you share your mView in xml